# Data on which topics angel investors have been interested through the years?

Tags: data-request, economics

I'm interested in knowing which topics angel investors have...well...invested in during the last years. Preferably in Europe.

This is because I want to prove that the "going green" movement is growing strong.

Do you know any dataset I can analyze? I only know pitchbook.com but it's paid.